# Replace Django model object with another

Tags: django, django-admin, django-orm

I'm working on an application where we have to review model changes before accepting them.

For this, when a user edits one of the company model objects in the app frontend, the form's initial data is filled with data from the original object and then stored into a new object that is flagged using the `origin_company` field (which is a foreign key to the previous version of the object).

So basically when someone edits a company, a new, inactive company is created.

To apply the changes, I want to copy all data from the changed company to the original company. (I'm doing this with custom django-admin actions.) The easiest way would probably be to start a transaction, delete the original company and change the primary key of the changed company to match the original company. But by doing that, the changed company is not UPDATEd, it is copied. And related database entries (FKs) are not updated either.

Is there an easy way to copy or move all data (including FK relations) from one model instance to another one? Or is my entire way of solving this problem messed up?

Here's the model definition:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ...
    origin_company = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name=u'CompanyEdits',
            null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
# get the company instance's data as a dict
data = company_instance.__dict__.copy()
# remove the `id` and `origin_company` keys. don't need these
del data['id']
del data['origin_company_id']
# update the origin company instance
Company.objects.filter(id=company_instance.origin_company.id).update(**data)
```

Comment: Thanks! There are some issues with your code though: First of all, `data` should be `company_instance.__dict__.copy()` and `'origin_company'` should be `'origin_company_id'`. Also, because we don't need the values of the id and origin_company fields, `del data['key']` is probably cleaner than `data.pop('key')`. What I did additionally is to filter out all items where the key starts with an underscore (e.g. `_state`).

Comment: Another problem is that foreign keys pointing to the company_instance aren't updated. There's probably no way around manually updating them, right?

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll accept your answer when you edit the first two issues mentioned above :)